# Does it make sense to share /usr as NAS over VMs?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, nas

I'm anticipating a number of *almost* heterogenous VMs. They will have the same installed applications but different configurations and application data.

It seems to me that it's probably possible for them to all share a `/usr` and diverge elsewhere in the filesystem.

Is this a sensible approach? I imagine `/usr` would then be a network drive, but then would these VMs still be able to boot?

Or is there a more sensible way to achieve the same goal? A fully-shared copy-on-write (i.e. reference-counted) filesystem, maybe? Or something else entirely? This is with CentOS on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been done in the past (and a common argument for the `/` vs `/usr` separation).

he current recommendation (and in many distros, a requirement) is that your **initramfs** needs to mount `/usr` if it's separate from `/`. Most Linux systems already use an initramfs to prepare the root filesystem, and it can be easily extended for `/usr` as well. Since it's really a full OS on its own, it can easily be configured to set up networking and mount `/usr` over NFS or SMB.

That said, remember that many packages install files outside `/usr` as well – e.g. directly to `/bin` (if your distribution hasn't merged it yet), or `/var/lib`, or `/etc`. Make sure to correctly replicate those across all VMs.